# onchange event in a "text input" to insert a value in a database when onchange event occured

Tags: javascript, mysql, database, input, onchange

I'm having a project where I want to do a "onchange" event, inside a text input form. What I want to happen is when I enter a value inside the text input form, then clicked outside it. It will insert the value in my sql database.

Is This Possible?

```
<td style="text-align:center">
    <form id="myForm" action="" method="post">
          <input  id="<?= $sample['sample'] ?>" placeholder="sample" type="text" name="sample" onchange="updateButton()">
    </form>
</td>
```

I expect when I clicked outside the text input, The value I typed in, will be saved in the Database.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <form action="#" id="formId">
    <input id="sample" type="text" placeholder="Enter data">
</form>

<script>
    window.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        // e.stopPropagation()

        const form = document.querySelector('#formId');
        
        if (sample.value) {
            form.submit();
            console.log(` save ${sample.value} in database`);
            sample.value = '';
        }      
    });

</script>
```